# Mobile questionnaire Wizard

Tags: user-expectation, validation

I am currently working on this app. We’ve done some user test on the feature and the feedback was positive. However, the sample was small and I still have some concerns about the design and we are not able to do another round of user testing as yet.

The user flow is to go through a 5 step wizard. Each screen will ask a question and the last one is a confirmation screen before you submit. Some of these questions will require some sort of validation e.g “a required input field”.

The design proposes to use a slider to go step by step.

In order to move to the next question, the user must press the ‘next’ button

My concern:
This is a common UI pattern and usually people have the ability to also swiping to navigate through the slides. In this case I am relying on a button to do this (considering that we need to trigger a validation check).

Do you think I should stick to the button or allow for both interactions?

Any thoughts, recommendations?

Thanks in advance.

[image: screen wireframe]

Answer (score 1):

I would say you can remove 'slides' altogether and let the user only click on Next to proceed further. You can show a progress indicator bar that moves according to what step the user is currently on. This would remove the ambiguity.

Example of what I am talking about: https://goodboxapp.com/make/?src=test
I have used this for an onboarding flow and have seen good results.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Raviteja.

 I agree with you. the whole 'slides' concept is causing confusion as I mentioned.
I like the idea you mentioned to use instead of the slides.

Answer (score 0):

I think for swiping to be appropriate, you'd need:

- A reason for allowing swiping back and forth, rather than just display each screen in turn (a stronger reason than just "because we can" or browsing a photo album allows it).
- It to make sense to defer any validation until the final submit. This can make sense if the values/validation rules are "interconnected".  However, if swiping *is* allowed, I think prohibiting it because the current setting (in isolation) is wrong would feel "odd".  (Or from the other angle, if it *doesn't* make sense to leave the current screen with an invalid value entered, it perhaps doesn't make sense to make [the current screen] part of a swipe-able set).

In short, if you want *local validation*, I don't think allowing swiping is appropriate. Swiping works (to me) when you can go freely back-and-forth and only need to validate "holistically".